# List creation with incremental values triggered by logical vector in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a vector of ordered integers of the same length as a vector of logicals. The list starts at 1 and continues with this value until a `TRUE` is encountered, which triggers an increase in the next element, and so on until all logicals are parsed.

I've got this working in a `for` loop, but I need to repeat the process many times over different groups and am wondering if something more efficient is recommended.

```
dat <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,
  TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,
  TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,
  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)

counter <- 1
output <- c()
for (i in dat) {
  output <- c(output, counter)
  if(i == T)
    counter <- counter + 1
}

output

> [1]  1  2  2  3  4  4  5  6  7  8  8  9  9 10 10 11 11 11 12 13 14
```

Thanks.

## Update

Per Stéphane's comment - `c(1, 1+cumsum(dat))[1:length(dat)]` works great, thanks!

Comment: can you please confirm your output once again, sholdn't it be 1,1,2 .. because you start with T, then F then T, hence 1,1,2

Comment: this is almost `c(1,1+cumsum(dat))`

Comment: `if(i == T)` and `if(i)` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` with an additional `FALSE` value as we want to increment the counter **after** we see a `TRUE` value and not **at** `TRUE` value.

```
cumsum(c(F, dat)) + 1 
#[1]  1  2  2  3  4  4  5  6  7  8  8  9  9 10 10 11 11 11 12 13 14 15
```

Since, we have added an extra `FALSE` value we need to remove the last value as it would give us `n+1` entries.

```
x <- cumsum(c(F, dat)) + 1
x[-length(x)]
#[1]  1  2  2  3  4  4  5  6  7  8  8  9  9 10 10 11 11 11 12 13 14
```